# Spring MVC RestController POST request Error 500

Tags: http, spring-mvc, tomcat7, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to build a REST Controller using Spring MVC in order to receive requests from an Android app. I have a GET request working fine. But, when I try to perform a POST request I got some errors.
If I perform the POST request from a form, everything works fine but, if I send the request from the Android app or from another tool (e.g. Postman) I get an Internal Server Error 500.

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:207)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:378)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:317)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:62)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:351)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1188)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I dont't think it's a code problem but I'm linking a simplified version of the controller and the form that actually performs the POST fine:

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class HeartRateController {

@PostMapping(value = ("/saveheartrates"))
public ResponseEntity<String> saveHeartRates() {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Worked", HttpStatus.OK);
}

}
```

Html form:

```
<form class="form-narrow form-horizontal" method="post" th:action="@{/saveheartrates}" th:fragment="signupForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Try post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using tomcat7 to run the app.

Comment: try `@PostMapping(value = ("/saveheartrates"))` without the `()` like `@PostMapping(value = "/saveheartrates")`

Comment: Hi, I think I tried all possible code variables but it doesn't work... Maybe it can be an issue related with Spring Security (that is also implemented in the project) because same POST request called from a form is working.